# sorting nested arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, nested

How do I sort out the following information from this nested arrays. I am getting JSONException at character 2 line 1. Data, Code and error is down below.

1. localteam_id
2. Visitorsteam_id
   3.Localteam_score
3. Visitorsteam_score
4. time
5. visitorsteam name

```
               {
            "data":[
            {
            "id": 11903988,
            "league_id": 498,
            "season_id": 16357,
         "stage_id": 77445097,
        "round_id": 176699,
         "group_id": null,
         "aggregate_id": null,
         "venue_id": null,
         "referee_id": null,
         "localteam_id": 237692,
         "visitorteam_id": 237702,
         "winner_team_id": null,
        "weather_report": null,
        "commentaries": false,
         "attendance": null,
          "pitch": null,
        "details": null,
          "neutral_venue": false,
         "winning_odds_calculated": false,
         "formations":{"localteam_formation": null, "visitorteam_formation": 
      null},
         "scores":{
         "localteam_score": 0,
         "visitorteam_score": 0,
         "localteam_pen_score": null,
         "visitorteam_pen_score": null,
         "ht_score": null,
         "ft_score": null,
         "et_score": null
         },
         "time":{"status": "TBA", "starting_at":{"date_time": "2019-09-14 
           00:00:00", "date": "2019-09-14",…},
         "coaches":{
         "localteam_coach_id": null,
         "visitorteam_coach_id": null
          },
         "standings":{
         "localteam_position": 12,
         "visitorteam_position": 4
         },
         "assistants":{"first_assistant_id": null, "second_assistant_id": 
  null, 
         "fourth_official_id": null},
       "leg": "1/1",
       "colors": null,
       "deleted": false,
       "localTeam":{"data":{"id": 237692, "legacy_id": null, "name": "Sochi 
     U20", 
         "short_code": null,…},
         "visitorTeam":{
         "data":{
         "id": 237702,
         "legacy_id": null,
         "name": "Lokomotiv Moskva U20",
         "short_code": null,
         "twitter": null,
         "country_id": 227,
         "national_team": false,
           "founded": null,
         "logo_path": null,
         "venue_id": null,
         "current_season_id": 16357
         }
      }
        ]
         }
```

**My code:**

```
JSONObject objj = parentArray.getJSONObject(i); 
league_id=objj.getString("data");
objj.league_id.[0];
```

**error :**

> org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: What is `parentArray`?  You do realize that your JSON is not an array, right?  It's an object that holds an array called `"data"`.

Comment: JSONArray parentArray =  new JSONArray(finaljson); it is the instance of the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finaljson);
```

You are trying to read an object(which is you whole json) to an array.

The array is "data" in your parent "JSONObject"

To get the league_id  your code should look like

```
JSONObject parentArray = new JSONObject(finaljson);

JSONArray obj = parentArray.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i =0 ; i< obj.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject dataObj = obj.getJSONObject(i);
  String league_id = data.getString("league_id");
//With proper Null checks
  String teamName = data.getJSONObject("localTeam").getJSONObject("data").getString("name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I want to loop through the object and get the elements.  I'll appreciate if you can help with the code. And how do I get the name of the local team since it is an inner element of data which is a sub array localteam.

Comment: Local team as per the json is an "Object" not an Array. Please find the updated answer. Each object has to be iterated one by one to get the inner Object

Comment: Thanks very much.  I implement it and see.